# Não consigo acessar elemento (child) porém ele existe (fullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Usando a função [eventAfterRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAfterRender) estou tentando acessar um elemento filho que existe, porém utilizando a função `find()`, aparentemente não está encontrando. Pelo console, consigo navegar até o elemento filho da seguinte forma:

```
[0] (a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-v-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.clicavel.rede)
 children
  [0] (div.fc-content)
   children
    [0] (div.fc-title)
     children
      [0] (img) <- esse é o elemento em questão
```

Tentei das seguintes formas, porém sem sucesso:

```
$(element).find('img');
$(element).find('.fc-title').child().first();
```

Usando a segunda tentativa, consigo chegar até o elemento .fc-title somente, retornando normalmente o elemento (`$(element).find('.fc-title')`)

Lembrando que o elemento imagem foi adicionado pelo título do evento ([Events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array))

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei à uma solução bizarra e, pelo que percebi, no momento que eu estava tentando usar o `find()`, o elemento ainda não tinha sido renderizado (não entendi direito), usei a função `setTimeout()` passando como tempo 0 (não entendi direito²) e aparentemente resolveu:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $(element).find('img');
}, 0);
```